# Ways to disable bestsellers aggregation

Tags: overrides, cron, reports, schedule

We have a heavy store with a 400k+ products. So we decide to completely remove bestsellers aggregation feature. This suppose to reduce sql load, and to free space, occupied this huge unneeded tables. 
How to do this properly?

Bestsellers aggregation defined in sales/observer::aggregateSalesReportBestsellersData method, which schedules by cron job.
There are some possible ways, that I see to solve this issue:

1. Override cron schedule. I've tried to override cron job schedule in
   local/MyModule/Sales/etc/config.xml, but it didn't work.
2. Override sales/observer model, and replace
       aggregateSalesReportBestsellersData with empty method

I prefer solution #1, but can't make it work. Here's config of my custom module:

```
<config>
    <crontab>
        <jobs>
            <aggregate_sales_report_bestsellers_data>
                <schedule><cron_expr>0 5 31 2 *</cron_expr></schedule>
                <run><model>sales/observer::aggregateSalesReportBestsellersData</model></run>
            </aggregate_sales_report_bestsellers_data>
        </jobs>
    </crontab>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `aggregate_sales_report_bestsellers_data` is a key of `jobs` array. So the module that runs last wins this key.

If I'm not mixing facts all you have to do is to name you module like `Zzz_Zzz` (not literally of course) to beat `Mage_Sales`.

Comment: My custom module named Store_Sales, so it can _beat_ core module by name...